# Passing Data from one Form to another by Overloading Constructor

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

Ok, I am trying to pass data from one form to another form using the overload constructor method. I could just use public variables or properties, but would like to use the overload method.

Here is the code section from my first form that calls the second form...

```
Private Sub dgvAllWO_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvAllWO.CellDoubleClick

    Dim I As Integer
    I = dgvAllWO.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells.Item(0).Value
    Dim frmWO(I) As New frmWorkOrder

End Sub
```

Here I have the code from the other form...

```
Public Class frmWorkOrder

    Public Sub New(ByVal ID As Integer)
      InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
      InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

End Class
```

After doing that, i now get an error on 'NEW' on this line of code on my first form.

```
Dim frmWO(I) As New frmWorkOrder
```

Error 1 Arrays cannot be declared with 'New'

Why is this happening? After overloading the constructor my form class is turned into an array? Im not sure what is happening here. I am grateful for any help or direction you can give me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB New is the constructor, so you need to pass the value to the constructor like this:

```
Dim frmWO As New frmWorkOrder(I)
```

If frmWO is an array, then something like this:

```
frmWO(I) = New frmWorkOrder(I)
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I know i was overlooking something rather simple.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
Dim frmWO(I) As New frmWorkOrder
```

should be

```
Dim frmWO As New frmWorkOrder(I)
```